# Restrict access to only necessary data-class accessors / getters

Tags: java, android, interface, adapter

I have a data class that is created in one class, and can be passed to one of several Android UI Activities that implement a specific Interface.

Each UI uses the same data, however, not all the UIs need all of the data. I was wondering if there was a **simple** solution that allows each UI to only use a specific part of the data (only use specific accessors / getters)

### ClickListener Handler Class

```
// ICalculatorAbstraction is what all my UI's implement. It has method... void updateResult(ExpressionState expression)
public final View.OnClickListener listenerOn(final ICalculatorAbstraction UI) {

    return listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Calculations

            ExpressionState expression = new ExpressionState.Builder()
                    .setFirstNumber(num1)
                    .setSecondNumber(num2)
                    .setTotal(total)
                    .setOperator(operator.getSign())
                    .build();

            UI.updateResult(expression); 

        }
    };

}
```

### ICalculatorAbstraction Interface

Again, all of my Android Activities (UIs) implement this interface

```
public interface ICalculatorAbstraction {

    ...

    void updateResult(ExpressionState result);

}
```

### Needs All Accessors UI

```
@Override
public void updateResult(ExpressionState result) {

    String results = String.format( // NOTE: this one needs ALL the accessors / getters!!
            "%s %s %s = %s",
            result.getFirstNumber(),
            result.getOperator(),
            result.getSecondNumber(),
            result.getTotal()
    );

    this.txtResult.setText(results);
```

### Needs One Accessor UI

```
@Override
public void updateResult(ExpressionState result) {

    String results = String.format( // NOTE: this one needs ONE accessor / getter!!
            "Wow. Such Calcuation. %s",
            result.getTotal()

            // NOTE: These should not be allowed in this instance because this UI does not use them
            // result.getFirstNumber()
            // result.getOperator()
            // result.getSecondNumber()

    );

    this.txtResult.setText(results);
```

**How can I change `updateResult(...)` (both in the interface and in the UI) so that the specific UI's `updateResult(...)` will only let me use the needed assessors / getters?**

I have tried to create a blank interface, and then created 2 abstract classes that implement that blank interface. The abstract classes had only the accessors / getters I needed, but when I tried to modify the above code, nothing worked.

**Is this possible?**

---

## Update

Here is what I would like to see - "my best possible solution" you can say.

### Needs All Accessors UI

```
@Override
public void updateResult(IAllAccessors result) {

    String results = String.format( 
            "%s %s %s = %s",
            result.getFirstNumber(),
            result.getOperator(),
            result.getSecondNumber(),
            result.getTotal()
    );

    this.txtResult.setText(results);
```

### Needs One Accessor UI

```
@Override
public void updateResult(IOneAccessorOnly result) {

    String results = String.format( 
            "Wow. Such Calcuation. %s",
            result.getTotal()            // I should not be able to do result.getFirstNumber(); for example

    );

    this.txtResult.setText(results);
```

### ExpressionState / Builder Class

```
public class ExpressionState implements IOneAccessorOnly, IAllAccessors {

    private ExpressionState(Builder builder) { ... }

    public double getFirstNumber() { ... }   // IAllAccessors
    public double getSecondNumber() { ... }  // IAllAccessors
    public String getOperator() { ... }      // IAllAccessors
    public double getTotal() { ... }         // IAllAccessors, IOneAccessorOnly

    public static class Builder { ... }

}
```

The problem with this solution, is that I cannot figure out what to do with my interface that I have above! I cannot have a parameter that will make the compiler happy with both UIs.

---

## Update 2

### I cannot have...

In my `ClickListener` class when creating `ExpressionState` with the builder

```
IOneAccessorOnly var = new ExperssionState.Builder()...
```

This is because in my `ClickListener` class, I don't know which one to create. It has to be very generic. In my UI's I want to simplify what I can use. I cannot do that with this approach

Because it does not know what to be, it has to be "everything"

```
ExpressionState var = new ExpressionState.Builder()...
```

It really cannot be anything other than that. The solution will have to deal with the UIs (Activities) specifically to narrow down what is allowed!!

Answer (score 1):

If Expression state is your own class I'd make it implement two different interfaces like so.

```
public class ExpressionState implements InterfaceOne, InterfaceTwo {
    public void interfaceOneGetterMethod()
    public void interfaceTwoGetterMethod()
}
```

in another file:

```
public interface InterfaceOne {
    public void interfaceOneGetterMethod();
```

and final file:

```
public interface InterfaceTwo {
    public void interfaceTwoGetterMethod();
```

Now when you create the ExpressionState objects assign them to objects defined as:

```
InterfaceTwo var = new ExperssionState(blah);
```

Or modify your builder to just return interfaces( even better )

Comment: This does not suit my needs at all. During ExpressionState creatation, the class does not know which one to create, so it has to be very broad-reaching. I want my UIs to try to reduce that over-reaching and only use what is needed. So if you could resubmit an answer that would be great. I will put your code in my question as something that I am not looking for, so others can know that

Comment: I have tried this code. It does NOT work!! I am trying your builder to return an interface; however, that is not working as I need it.

Comment: The whole idea of a builder is or factory is that building the object itself is determined by a different method being called or different parameters being sent it at construction time. You might want to look up the Builder design pattern or different Factory design patterns before responding like this. The use of interfaces is considered best practices for encapsulating data and hiding implementation.

Comment: The use of the Builder Pattern is to avoid using the telescoping anti-pattern. This is why I used it. Like I said, your solution does not fit my needs as stated in the question. Please update your answer. I am a little intrigued by factory you mention. Does that fit my needs?

Comment: My issue is not the use of interfaces. My code is loaded with them, and I plan on using more. I understand encapsulation and hiding implementation. I encourage that, so you have me wrong here. I have tried you way....it does not work because you answer did not take into account my whole issue